# ~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv: line 36: ./bin/readlink: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, wsl-2, pyenv

I'm using pyenv on wsl, and whenever I am at the root directory, I get this error message everytime I execute a command:

```
~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv: line 36: ./bin/readlink: No such file or directory
pyenv: no such command `version-name'
```

Here is the content of the line 36:

```
  resolve_link() {
    $READLINK "$1"
  }
```

I have seen this issue once on StackOverflow, unfortunately OP solved it without elaborating on how.